# Datastore on flex nodejs appengine stopped working - bad gateway 502

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-nodejs-client, app-engine-flexible

After making some updates to an app I'm working on, I pushed the app up via `gcloud app deploy --version dev` and everything seemed to push just fine, but upon further inspection, any of my calls (get or post) that use the `@google-cloud/datastore` package fail with `Bad Gateway 502 - nginx` error.

I've put in console.logs everywhere and they never get past the line before any `datastore.whatever()` calls. tested with .save, .runQuery, and .update.

Weirder still, i can access the datastore just fine via my console, and my localhost still works 100% as expected, pulling the data from my cloud datastore.

I even tried to narrow it down via `manual_scaling` update i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012797/google-app-engine-502-bad-gateway-with-nodejs) but that didn't seem to do anything

thoughts?

Comment: we are having the same problem

Comment: i just reverted to old production version and datastore seems fine - i think cloud build might be broken or not deploying right?

Comment: no idea, will check more tomorrow. We are using "asia-northeast1" region by the way

Comment: ive been deploying to us central and east, dont remember numbers exactly

Comment: https://status.cloud.google.com/ shows a Compute Engine outage, but nothing else.

Comment: I've been unable to observe this error in testing using my own application. If this is still occurring, anybody affected should open a [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) thread with label "Restrict-View-EditIssue" so that they can privately upload their code for us to compare with our own working code.