# 502 server error in Google App Engine Flexible when load testing with JMeter

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, spring-boot, jmeter

I have deployed a simple Spring boot app in Google App Engine Flexible. The app. has two APIs, one to add the user data into the DB (xxx.appspot.com/add) the other to get all the user data from the DB (xxx.appspot.com/all).

I wanted to see how GAE scales for the load, hence used JMeter to create a load with 100 user concurrency ramped up in 10 seconds and calls these two APIs in half a second delay, forever. While it runs fine for sometime (with just one instance), it starts to fail after 30 seconds or so with a "java.net.SocketException" or "The server responded with a status of 502".

After this error, when I try to access the same API from the browser, it displays,

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your
>   request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

The service is back to normal after 30 mins or so, and whenever the load test happens it repeats the same behavior as mentioned above. I expect GAE to auto-scale based on the load coming in to handle it without any down time (using multiple instances), instead it just crashes or blocks the service (without any information in the log). My app.yaml configuration is,

```
runtime: java
env: flex
service: hello-service
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 10
```

I am a bit stuck with this one, Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see in the Logs Viewer? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012797/google-app-engine-502-bad-gateway-with-nodejs

Comment: @user7294900 I have changed it to manual scaling in app.yaml. However, I could not find the way to switch from the "google owned" VM to "self owned" VM in the console. I could not find the instances in the GCE area. Also the detailed error I get in the log is in this link *https://jpst.it/13hHk*.

Comment: @DanCornilescu The high level logs show this *https://jpst.it/13hIV*. The detailed logs are mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: I have tried disabling and enabling the "health check". Added cpu_utilization, target_utilization properties in app.yaml. However, still I face the same issue. The app also restarts periodically even after overriding it in my code.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Further I checked the nginx logs and found "[error] 32#32: *56619 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxxx, server: , request: "GET /all HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://x.x.x.x:8080/_ah/health", host: "x.x.x.x".

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't have any idea - I'm not very familiar with java and/or flex. I can only suggest verifying that your app's health check and starting works properly at a slower rate first - maybe not 100 users, but only just enough to get a 2nd instance launch attempt. Or manually stop a normally running instance to check its automatic re-launch sequence, without a lot of traffic. That needs to work perfectly before you embark in serious scalability tests.

Comment: Are you hitting any quota limits? Console > App Engine > Quotas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to increase the resource configuration, details below.

> Given that I did not set a resource parameter, it defaulted to the pre-defined values for both CPU and Memory. In this case, the default
>   memory was set at 0.6GB. App Engine Flex instances uses about 0.4GB
>   for overhead processes. Given Java is known to consume higher memory, there is a
>   great likelihood that the overhead processes consumed more than the
>   approximate 0.4GB value. Now instances in App Engine are restarted due
>   to a variety of reasons including optimization due to memory use. This
>   explains why your instances went off and it shows Tomcat is starting
>   up (they got restarted) and ends up in 502 error due to the nginx is
>   not able to complete the request. Fixing the above may lessen if not completely eliminate the 502s.

After I have specified the resources attribute and increased the configuration in app.yaml 502 error seems to be gone.

Comment: Thanks KingKari! I had the same problem and no idea of how to solve it. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: Thanks KayKay, I've submitted a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121068500 .